# Get overridden functions of subclass

Tags: python, reflection, overriding, subclass

Is there a way to get all overriden functions of a subclass in Python?

Example:

```
class A:
    def a1(self):
        pass

    def a2(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    def a2(self):
        pass

    def b1(self):
        pass
```

Here, I would like to get a list `["a2"]` for an object of class `B` (or for the class object itself) since class `B` overrides only a single method, namely `a2`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can access the parent classes with [`cls.__bases__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__), find all attributes of the parents with [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir), and access all the attributes of the class itself with [`vars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars):

```
def get_overridden_methods(cls):
    # collect all attributes inherited from parent classes
    parent_attrs = set()
    for base in cls.__bases__:
        parent_attrs.update(dir(base))

    # find all methods implemented in the class itself
    methods = {name for name, thing in vars(cls).items() if callable(thing)}

    # return the intersection of both
    return parent_attrs.intersection(methods)
```

```
>>> get_overridden_methods(B)
{'a2'}
```

Comment: `vars` was the thing i was missing. big thanks for the (incredibly) fast answer!

Comment: `parent_attrs` in one line if you want: `parent_attrs = {a for b in cls.__bases__ for a in dir(b)}`

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `__mro__` tuple, which holds the method resolution order.

For your example:

```
>>> B.__mro__
( <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>)
```

So you could loop over that tuple and check if a `B` method is also in one of the other classes.

Comment: This will not exclude predefined method, like any **dunder**  method , `__init__, __eq__, ....... etc`

Answer (score -1):

```
class A:

    def a1(self):
        pass

    def a2(self):
        pass


class B(A):

    def a2(self):
        super().a2()  
        pass

    def b1(self):
        pass
obj = B()

obj.a2()   # ***first give the output of parent class then child class***
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Classes `A` and `B` can't be modified. OP wants to know which of `B`'s methods override one of `A`'s methods.